# WebApi - The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, asp.net-web-api

**Question Background:**

I have a basic WebApi project hosted as a WebApp in Azure.

**The Issue:**

The problem I have is If I access any method other than a 'GET' type then I'm receiving the following error in my JSON response:

```
The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'
```

**The Code:**

The following code is how the project currently is.

`RouteConfig.cs` class:

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Home",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

The `ValuesController` controller class:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{

    private List<CompanyData> _company;

    public ValuesController()
    {
        _company = new List<CompanyData>
        {
            new CompanyData
            {
                CompanyName = "SmallTech.Ltd",
                CompanyOwner = "John Smith",
                CompanyIndustry = "Electronic Components",
                EmployeeNo = "3"
            }

        };
    }

    public List<CompanyData> GetCompanyData()
    {
        return _company;
    }


     //GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "Test GET Method"};
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST api/values
    public void Post(string value)
    {
        string test = value;
    }

    // PUT api/values/5
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE api/values/5
    [HttpDelete]
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
```

An example of calling the above Delete method when the error occurs is:

http://testwebapisite.azurewebsites.net/api/values/Delete/5

I have read other people having the same issue and using the HTTP attributes from the `System.Net.MVC`. I can confirm I'm not using this and am using `System.Net.Http.HttpPostAttribute.

**Any help working out why I'm receiving the GET error message would be great.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to access an action which clearly specifies delete as its verb via a GET request.

By default the browser will do a GET request if you paste a url so thats pretty much easy to test but for the other verbs you'll have to use an actual rest/http client to specify the verb. You can use Postman or Rest Console if you use chrome to dev/test

In addition to those tools, you might want to have [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) installed .. it will help you track all http activity (both sent/received) you'll know exactly what you are sending and receiving from the wire

You could also do this from code if you want using `HttpClient`.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://testwebapisite.azurewebsites.net/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


                   HttpResponseMessage response = await client.DeleteAsync("api/values/5");
                }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate please? I can see that myself but I'm not sure 'why' that is happening?

Comment: No idea why i got a downvote. I'd love to find out what aspects of my answer is wrong :)

Comment: My guess is because it's too short an answer doesn't really explain in full?

Comment: @DavidG Oh .. i guess that could be it. Maybe i'll try adding to it from my suggestions in the comment.

Comment: @scartag apologies I think that was me? Even though I actually accepted your answer as correct, not sure what happened there. Yes this is exactly what I was after. I'm now happily using Fiddler to hit the API end points. Again thanks for your answer and sorry for the mix up!

Comment: @user1352057 No worries :) .. The answer has gotten more info.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't shown the code that you are using to invoke the API, but I suspect you are not using the DELETE HTTP verb. The resource you are accessing has URI or `http://testwebapisite.azurewebsites.net/api/values/5` - note the action name is not specified. Rather, as the comment of your method suggests, you should be using the DELETE HTTP verb. Example:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
    await client.DeleteAsync("http://testwebapisite.azurewebsites.net/api/values/5");
```